# Visa for brother with less income

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

We are 3 brothers.
I am going with family (wife and 2 kids) to the UK for tourism. My second brother, who is in business (but the business registration is in the thirrd brother's name) also wants to come.

Since the business registration is in the third brother's name, he does not have sufficient funds, but a reasonable bank balance.
I am willing to pay for him and take care of his expenses.

How do I apply for his visa for so it does not get rejected?

Comment: He does not have sufficient funds but a reasonable bank balance?

Comment: The funds aren't the only important part of the application: he (and you) will need to show ties to the home country. Does he have a history of salary or similar payments from the business he is in?

Answer (score 4):

Your brother does not need **funds**, he needs a reasonable pattern of **income and expenditures**. See [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) excellent answer by Gayot Fow.

Your second brother runs a business which is held in the third brother's name? Have the business owner start paying the worker a regular, monthly *salary* for his work. After some months, there second brother will have regular deposits in his bank account.